# wordpress custom post template not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I created another menu in wordpress dashboard, it functions like the post menu, I wanted to apply a customized template to that menu I created. sample, the menu is called "TEchnologies Page", in my editor I created a technologies.php page which initialize the contents I want to display on my technology template, I already registered the the new menu category to functions.php but the problem is wordpress does not recognize the template I created for that menu, when I opened the content type it still has the normal appearance..

I have this code;

functions.php

```
  // category
  function TechnologiesRegister() {
     $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Technologies', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Technologies', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New Technologies', 'portfolio item'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Technologies'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Technologies'),
    'new_item' => __('New Technologies'),
    'view_item' => __('View Technologies'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Technologies'),
    'not_found' => __('Nothing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
    'rewrite' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
);
   register_post_type('technologies', $args);
 }
    add_action('init', 'TechnologiesRegister');
 // end category
```

technologies.php

```
   <?php
     /* Template Name: Technologies Page*/
   ?>

    <?php get_header(); ?>
  <head>
       <style type="text/css">.social-wrap {margin-top: 79px !important;}</style> 
      </head>
    <div class="container technologies">
        <div class="row">

           <?php
             $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
             $args = array('post_type' => 'technologies', 'paged' => $paged, 'posts_per_page' => 500);
     query_posts($args);
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        ?>     
        <div class="span3 technologies-icon">
            <?php
            $attachment_id = get_field('image');
            $size = "full";
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, $size);
            ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" class="pull-right" />                
        </div>
        <div class="span9 technologies-desc">
            <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?> 

</div>
```

Comment: So you registered a custom post type and THEN you are looping that post type on a page. It's not going to look different if you don't style it. Put this in your .css -> `.technologies {border: 10px solid red;}`

Comment: My problem is, wordpress does not recognized the template that I created, it does not recognize this file technologies.php..what could be the problem to this?..

Comment: in your page template section in the right side of your page editor does the technologies page template one of the options?

Comment: @loQ - yes it is, but the content does not change, it supposed to have an image upload feature..

Comment: Have you made a page, and then chosen the correct template? Or is this going to be a list of "technologies" that loop like a magazine or blog post? In that case you'll need a "archive-technology.php." Can you rewrite your question to say what you really want and use the correct words? That would clarify. Again, to be clear: you registered a post type(this adds a menu item to the admin panel) - Then you are looping `the image` and `the title` and `the content` from that post type.

Comment: How come you aren't using the featured image instead of this verbose approach? What you probably want is an archive page. To get those in your options in the menu you'll need to do a few more things as well.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/add-custom-post-types-archive-to-nav-menus/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `technologies.php` by itself is not enough for WordPress to recognize automatically.

You need to rename the theme file `archive-technologies.php` (for loop) or `single-technologies.php` (for single post), per the [WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates).